# Qt Creator: unit-test: is it possible to have four ways of building a code (debug, release, debug|release and Test)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt-creator, config, qmake

I am working with unit-test and I managed to create two projects in Qt-Creator: a `unit-test project` and `Application project`. Compiling both of them separately, I am very happy with both projects.

Then, I managed to link the two projects together, i.e.: testing a class (`myClass.cpp`) from my `Application project` using the `unit-test project`. the link was done by adding:

```
#INCLUDEPATH myApplicationProjectPath 
#SOURCES myApplicationProjectPath/myClass.cpp
```

to the `.pro file` of the `unit-test project` and everything is working fine and my unit test is functioning. (I am now building a lib instead of adding paths and classes).

In the meanwhile, in the `.pro file` of the `Application project`, I am having something like:

```
#CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
message(Debug bulid)
}
```

which is a conditional statement to whether compile the code in a Debug or debug|Relase modes.

taking into account [that](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/what_does_the_syntax_configdebugdebugrelease_mean_what_does_the_1st_argumen) (`qmake` processes a `pro file` up to three times depending on what the configuration is set to. Usually it will do it three times. Once for debug, once for release and one final one for debug_and_release.), what if I tried to use `#CONFIG` in my `.pro file` of the `Application project` to add a `Test mode`. so, when I try to build my project I will have the option to select whether to build in Test, debug or release mode.

doing so will allow me to avoid building separate project for unit-test and just add the classes I need to test within the `#SOURCES` section within the Test mode option.

so, is it possible to have four ways of building a code (debug, release, debug|release and Test) ?

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is part of the `CONFIG` can be tested for as a scope for conditionals (see: [QMake Configuration & Scope](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-advanced-usage.html#configuration-and-scopes)).  That means you can add your own meaning for "Test".

*For Example*

The following will add sources when "unittest" is added to the CONFIG using `CONFIG += unittest`

```
unittest {
    SOURCES += my_unittests.cc
}
```